# horizontal menu, position fixed, next to div

Tags: css, menu, fixed

I have a top horizontal menubar 100% width, centeraligned, with fixed position, so its not scrolling with the page.

But I also want a name (named test in example) in the left side of the menu, inline of the menu.

But even though I uses inline-block, it stepsdown according to the left sided div.

```
    <div class="name">test</div >

<div id="menu"> 
        <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu3</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu4</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu5</a></li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.name {
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
color: #ffffff ;
Width: 99%;
display:  ;
position:fixed;
z-index:2;
padding: 5px;
top: 2px;
}


#menu {
 background: #bbbbbb;
 top: 0px;
 height: 35px;
 width: 99.8% ;
 text-align: center ;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:1;
 }


}

#menu ul{
display: ;
height: auto;
padding: 8px 0px;
margin: 0px;
z-index:3;
}

#menu li {
display: inline;
z-index:3;
}



#menu a {
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
color: red;  
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: bottom;  
padding: 20px; 

}
```

see example: https://jsfiddle.net/sm6npxdc/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset and changed some padding, height and width values.
Please try the following css:

```
*{
  margin: 0;  
  padding: 0;
}
.name {
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
color: #ffffff ;
display:  ;
position:fixed;
z-index:2;
padding: 5px;
top: 2px;
}
#menu {
 background: #bbbbbb;
 top: 0px;
 width: 99.8% ;
 text-align: center ;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:1;
}
#menu ul{
display: ;
height: auto;
margin: 0px;
z-index:3;
}
#menu li {
display: inline;
z-index:3;
}
#menu a {
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
color: red;  
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: bottom;  
padding: 10px;
}
```

fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sm6npxdc/10/)

Comment: wouldnt this mess up rest of css:  *{
  margin: 0;  
  padding: 0;

Comment: just tried and yes it messes up every thing else I have in underlying pages.

Comment: Fixed, it was my tables which just needed a margin: auto

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
.name {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  Width: 99%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 2px;
}
#menu {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  top: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 99.8%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
#menu ul {
  line-height: 2.000;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0px;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0px 12px;
}
#menu a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">test</div>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php?menu=1" border="0" alt="menu1">menu5</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div style='clear:both; margin-top:40px;'>
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam.
In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla
metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor
neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam
furor iste tuus nos eludet? Quem ad finem sese effrenata iactabit audacia? CICERO Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis
sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum
sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer
lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi
lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede.
```

or see this demo in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm6npxdc/4/)

Comment: Thx for reply, but just tried this, and yes the menu goes inline with the "name" div, but every menu url is under every menu text.